# How can I get the sum of the same id values in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to find the sum of the same id values.

```
$tournament = Tournament::find($id);
 
$topTen = DB::table('match_scoreboard_batting')
            ->join('matches','match_scoreboard_batting.match_id','=','matches.id')
            ->where('matches.tournament_id',$id)
            ->select('match_scoreboard_batting.player_id','match_scoreboard_batting.runs')
            ->sum('match_scoreboard_batting.runs');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($topTen);
```

I know how to get the sum of all id values. But how can I get the sum of the same id values?

Comment: you can use group by and put aggregation function sum in column you want the value to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this query.

```
$topTen = DB::table('match_scoreboard_batting')
            ->join('matches','match_scoreboard_batting.match_id','=','matches.id')
            ->where('matches.tournament_id',$id)
            ->select('match_scoreboard_batting.player_id', \DB::raw(' sum(match_scoreboard_batting.runs) as runs'));
```

You can use :

from laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

```
DB::raw('SUM(price) as total_sales')
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks bro.. It Works

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum()` would cause to group by primary key (I guess here is player_id) automatically. If you want to get sum() of each match, tournament, or player you are supposed to add `->groupBy('some_id')` in your query.